# Calling PL/pgSQL Stored Procedures from Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stored-procedures, plpgsql, rails-postgresql

I am working on a project where I am the database designer/admin in a PostgreSQL environment. The leader has decided to use Rails for the application logic and recruited a Rails programmer.

The Rails programmer said that he usually programs all application code and doesn't like the lack of control presented by having someone pass him a stored procedure, and that he has never done it in rails.

The database utilizes a lot of inheritence/EERM, so stored procedures and triggers will make his job a lot easier, in addition to the performance benefits from using procs.

I have four questions:

1) How to call a pl/pgSQL stored procedure from Rails with no return value

2) How to call a pl/pgSQL stored procedure from Rails with a single return value (1 row/1 column)

3) How to call a pl/pgSQL stored procedure from Rails with a 1 row many column return value.

4) How to call a pl/pgSQL stored procedure from Rails using an OUT parameter ?

Thanks!

Comment: You're going to have a bad time unless you can convince your Rails programmer to use something like [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org). The default Rails ORM (ActiveRecord) doesn't believe that the database should contain any logic and doesn't understand anything more complicated than `select *` and simple joins, you'll be fighting it all the time if you violate the conventions by using "fancy" things like triggers, stored procedures, or even prepared statements.

Comment: Yeah... proc and inheritance based DB + ActiveRecord will lead you straight into http://thedailywtf.com/ territory. You've got to live with the decision to go for Rails (and presumably its ActiveRecord ORM) and throw your DB design out the window then make one that follows the ActiveRecord convensions (no silly things like "foreign keys" or "constraints", who'd want them anyway?). Alternately, change the decision and see if as Mu notes you can get them to at least use a sane-ish ORM.

Answer (score 9):

Hello I'm using this code to work with PgSQL stored procedures
This covers all except your last question

```
   class SpActiveRecord < ActiveRecord::Base

      self.abstract_class = true
      #without return value
      def self.execute_sp(sql, *bindings)
        perform_sp(:execute, sql, *bindings)
      end
      #select many return values
      def self.fetch_sp(sql, *bindings)
        perform_sp(:select_all, sql, *bindings)
      end
      #select single return value
      def self.fetch_sp_val(sql, *bindings)
        perform_sp(:select_value, sql, *bindings)
      end

      protected
      def self.perform_sp(method, sql, *bindings)
        if bindings.any?
          sql = self.send(:sanitize_sql_array, bindings.unshift(sql))
        end
        self.connection.send(method, sql)
      end

    end
```

Example

```
class Invoice < SpActiveRecord

 def create_or_update
       raise ReadOnlyRecord if readonly? or !new_record?

        self.id = fetch_sp_val("SELECT * FROM billing.invoice_generate(?,?,?)", 
                               self.account_id,
                               self.start_date,
                               self.end_date)

       @new_record = false
       true
   end
end
```